# ZSH -- cd into directory without full path name

Tags: zsh, cd-command

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802017/bash-shell-search-for-subfolder-in-current-dir-and-cd-into-it

would like to implement this, as I don't want to `tabcomplete`.

when I type the command:

```
cd `find . -name test -type d`
```

I get this error:

```
find: ./usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
```

I've tried cd'ing with fzf and ranger. but it's all a mess.

Also I thought the reason behind the error turning up is because the folder is hidden but it doesn't work with visible folders either ...

Comment: You would get an error from `find` for any directory that you don't have access to, that's not strange and may be ignored by redirecting the standard error to `/dev/null`.  However, it's not clear what you want to do when there are multiple `test` directories or when any of the found directories are located under a path containing spaces. If you're using `zsh`, you also have access to the `**` glob and therefore probably don't need to use `find` at all.

Comment: Um, `sudo cd \`find . -name test -type d\``

Comment: I get some wild behaviour then.

sudoing doesn't work

Comment: don't know what to do with ** , sorry noob here

Comment: @rando What is that going to achieve? The `find` process would run and finish running before `sudo cd` is executed, and `sudo cd` would definitely not work (requires `cd` to be an external executable, and would not be able to change the working directory for the user's original shell, only for the `sudo` shell, which terminates immediately).

Comment: It's still unclear how you want to handle the cases I mentioned, i.e. 1) multiple directories called `test` are found, and 2) the pathname to the found directory or directories contain spaces, tabs or newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is by `find` telling you that it's unable to find files in that directory as it doesn't have permission to read or enter it.

That

> ```
> cd `find . -name test -type d`
> ```

syntax is wrong anyway as it's splitting the output of `find` on any character of `$IFS` instead of just newline (not to mention that there's nothing stopping file paths from containing newline characters), and may end up passing more than one argument to `cd`.

In zsh, you'd rather do:

```
cd ./**/test(/[1])
```

Which would `cd` into the first (in alphabetical order) directory under any level of subdirectories whose name is `test`, ignoring hidden ones.

Glob expansions ignore errors upon crawling the directory tree, though in zsh, you can check for errors using the special `$ERRNO` variable which holds the error number value from the last failing system call that the shell made.

In any case, doing `sudo cd` as you mentioned in comment doesn't make sense. `cd` is a builtin command of the shell to change the working directory of the shell process. `sudo` is an external command to run a command as a different user (`s`witch `u`ser `do`). [Some systems do have a standalone `cd` utility](/q/50058) (it's even required by POSIX), but all it does is change the current directory of its own process and then exits that process, so it won't help you change the current working directory of the current shell process.

`zsh` has builtin support to change effective user id, but it's still within the limits as set by the system. For instance, a `zsh` process running as `root` would be able to change its effective uid to anything and back to root again:

```
# id -un
root
# EUID=1000
$ id -un
chazelas
$ EUID=0
# id -un
root
```

But not after you've set `$UID` or `$USERNAME` (which also sets uid, gid and additional gids).

It should be possible in theory to  change the current working directory of a process to some directory they don't have access to via the help of a setuid helper (such as `sudo`) using a special file descriptor passing mechanism, but I don't know of any shell with support for that. And in any case, once you've managed to `cd` there, you wouldn't be able to do anything with the files there, so it wouldn't be of any help:

```
$ cd /var/spool/cron/crontabs
cd: permission denied: /var/spool/cron/crontabs
$ sudo zsh
/home/chazelas# cd /var/spool/cron/crontabs
/var/spool/cron/crontabs# USERNAME=chazelas
/var/spool/cron/crontabs$
```

I now have an unprivileged shell with `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, a restricted directory as its current working directory.

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs$ pwd
/var/spool/cron/crontabs
/var/spool/cron/crontabs$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

If you need to do things in a shell from within a restricted directory, you'll likely want to start a shell as a user with access to that directory. For example:

```
sudo sh -c 'cd /restricted/dir && do-something-there'
```

Some implementations of the `env` command can also `chdir()` to some directory before executing a command there which would save having to invoke a shell:

```
sudo env -C /restricted/dir do-something-there
```

(above assuming the default target user for `sudo` (generally `root`) has access to `/restricted/dir`, use the `-u` option to specify the user).

Comment: For clarification , `sudo` actually stands for `Super User DO`.